# How to fit and plot exponential decay function using ggplot2 and linear approximation

Tags: r, ggplot2, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit exponential decay functions on data which has only few time points. I would like to use the [exponential decay equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay) `y = y0*e^(-r*time)` in order to compare `r` (or eventually half-life) between datasets and factors. I have understood that using a linear fit instead of nls is a better alternative for this particular function [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844522/fitting-a-function-in-r),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938042/fitting-exponential-decay-with-no-initial-guessing)], if I want to estimate the confidence intervals (which I do).

Copy this to get some example data:

```
x <- structure(list(Factor = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), 
time = c(0.25, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.27, 0.29, 0.29, 0.33, 
0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.39, 0.4, 0.4, 0.41, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 
0.45, 0.47, 0.51, 0.51, 0.52, 0.57, 0.57, 0.57, 0.57, 0.58, 
    0.58, 0.58, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.61, 0.61, 0.61, 0.62, 0.62, 
    0.64, 0.64, 0.67, 0.67, 0.67, 0.67, 0.69, 0.7, 0.7, 0.71, 
    0.76, 0.76, 0.77, 0.77, 0.79, 0.79, 0.8, 0.8, 0.83, 0.83, 
    0.84, 0.84, 0.86, 0.86, 0.87, 0.87, 18.57, 18.57, 18.57, 
    18.58, 18.69, 18.69, 18.7, 18.7, 18.7, 18.71, 18.71, 18.71, 
    18.74, 18.74, 18.74, 18.79, 18.85, 18.85, 18.86, 18.88, 18.89, 
    18.89, 18.89, 18.93, 18.93, 18.95, 18.95, 18.95, 18.96, 18.96, 
    18.96, 20.57, 20.57, 20.61, 20.62, 20.66, 20.67, 20.67, 20.67, 
    20.72, 20.72, 20.72, 21.18, 21.19, 21.19, 21.19, 21.22, 21.22, 
    21.22, 21.23, 21.25, 21.25, 21.25, 21.25, 87.58, 87.58, 87.64, 
    87.64, 87.65, 87.84, 87.85, 87.91, 87.91, 87.91, 89.27, 89.28, 
    89.28, 89.36, 89.36, 89.4, 89.4, 110.91, 112.19, 112.19, 
    112.2, 112.2, 112.24, 112.25, 112.25, 112.26, 185.6, 185.6, 
    185.63, 185.63, 185.64, 213, 234.96, 234.97, 234.97, 234.98, 
    235.01, 235.01, 235.02, 235.02), y = c(58.1, 42.9, 54.2, 
    45.3, 51.2, 44.4, 56.9, 53.4, 61.3, 49.3, 54.4, 55.6, 25.6, 
    48.1, 50.8, 54.7, 41.8, 46.2, 39.5, 51.7, 37.7, 43.1, 44.6, 
    48.4, 50.9, 62.5, 58.6, 47.8, 44.3, 55.6, 44.9, 49.1, 49.1, 
    60.3, 40.8, 57.6, 42.9, 60, 49.4, 54.1, 37.8, 46.5, 59, 64.3, 
    48, 54.3, 51.7, 59, 57.1, 29.4, 49.2, 50, 41.3, 40.5, 43.4, 
    48.6, 38.5, 35.7, 43.6, 60, 32, 27.3, 34.3, 44.4, 36.5, 25.4, 
    22.6, 25.5, 24.1, 18.9, 25, 5.9, 19.6, 15.7, 32.3, 14.3, 
    23.4, 29.4, 17, 18.3, 34.4, 26.4, 35.7, 22.6, 23.5, 19.3, 
    25.5, 34.7, 45.5, 38.1, 33.8, 47.9, 32.3, 32.1, 43, 27.8, 
    33.3, 25.5, 22.2, 29.2, 24.2, 22.8, 19.2, 31.6, 20.8, 26.4, 
    35.8, 50, 10.7, 24, 54.3, 67, 77.7, 51.7, 64.8, 49.3, 57.8, 
    43.2, 17, 17.4, 36.4, 60.2, 36, 4, 0, 0, 9.1, 2.9, 24.3, 
    18.8, 36, 16.3, 18.4, 17.1, 26.5, 29.3, 17.4, 23.1, 25.7, 
    32.7, 16.3, 14.6, 13.7, 16.2, 16.7, 21.9, 0, 0, 11.6, 8.6, 
    0, 3.7, 3.6, 5, 3.2, 0, 2.5, 5.7)), .Names = c("Factor", 
"time", "y"), row.names = c(NA, -158L), class = "data.frame")
```

I manage to do this using the standard logarithmic function `log(y) = x` (thanks to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000926/how-can-i-overlay-timeseries-models-for-exponential-decay-into-ggplot2-graphics)), but fail when trying to fit several parameters in linear space.

```
summary(lm(log(y) ~ time, data = x, subset = Factor)) # I need the summary statistics to compare models
ggplot(x, aes(x = time, y = y, color = Factor)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "glm", family = gaussian(lin="log"), start=c(5,0))
```

[image]

Here is what I have tried:

```
## Summary

log.dec.fun <- function(N, r, time) -r*time + log(N) # The function in linear format

summary(glm(y ~ log.dec.fun(N, r, time), data = x, subset = Factor, start = c(5,0)))
# Error in log.dec.fun(N, r, time) : object 'r' not found

predict(glm(y ~ log.dec.fun(N, r, time), data = x, start = c(5,0)))
# Error in log.dec.fun(N, r, time) : object 'r' not found

## Plot

ggplot(x, aes(x = time, y = y, color = Factor)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "glm", formula = y ~ log.dec.fun(N, r, time), start = c(5,0))
#Error in log.dec.fun(N, r, time) : object 'r' not found
#Error in if (nrow(layer_data) == 0) return() : argument is of length zero
```

I can manage to get quite satisfactory models using `nls`, but I have learned that calculating confidence intervals for `nls` functions verges upon magic and beginners should not even try doing that.

```
dec.fun <- function(N, r, time) N*exp(-r*time) ## The function in non-linear form
g <- c()
for(i in 1:nlevels(x$Factor)){
z <- subset(x, Factor == levels(x$Factor)[i])
g <- append(g, predict(nls(y ~ dec.fun(N, r, time), data = z, start = list(N = 5, r = 0))))}
x <- x[with(x, order(Factor, time)),]

x$modelled <- g

ggplot(x, aes(x = time, color = Factor)) + geom_point(aes(y = y)) + geom_line(aes(y = modelled))
```

[image]
So my question is **how to fit exponential decay functions using R, ggplot2 and linear approximation?** There is an [answer in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938042/fitting-exponential-decay-with-no-initial-guessing), where @Joe Kington indicates that this is possible and provides the Python code. Unfortunately I do not understand Python.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to make separate estimates for each level of your variable `Factor` in your linear approximation?  You linear approximation is just a simple linear regression on the log scale, where your `log(N)` is the intercept and your `-r` is the slope.  If you want to allow your slope and intercept to vary by group, just include group in the model.  Such as: `glm(y ~ Factor*time-1, data = x, family = gaussian(link = "log"), start = c(5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0))`.

Comment: This was admittedly a stupid question. As you say the slope is `r` and the intercept is `N`. Hence the exponential decay function is just a normal logarithmic function with a negative slope, if you `log` it. I somehow got confused with these equations. If you do not mind, maybe you could elaborate your comment as an answer so you would get some reputation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you simply need to allow for separate slopes and intercepts to be fit by your grouping variable `Factor` when you fit the model with the natural logarithm transformation for the response.  I call this a *separate lines* model.  Then you can predict and get confidence (or prediction) intervals on the log scale for each `Factor`, and back-transform to see the lines (much like the graphs in your original post from `ggplot2`.

Example of a separate lines model in R:

```
fit1 = lm(y ~ time*Factor, data = x)
summary(fit1)
```

The output of this model will show the estimated intercept for the reference level of `Factor`, the estimated slope for the reference level, and the difference in intercepts and slopes between the reference level and all other levels.

Alternatively, you could code the separate lines model:

```
fit2 = lm(y ~ time + time:Factor - 1, data = x)
summary(fit2)
```

This will show you the estimated intercept and slope separately for each level of `Factor` in your output.

To make lines based on the model, you can use `predict` and then back-transform to the original scale.  Assuming a natural log transformation (and adding the values to your original dataset):

```
(x$pred = exp(predict(fit1)) )
```

You can also calculate and exponentiate your confidence intervals to the original scale if that's what you need.

```
exp(predict(fit1, interval = "confidence"))
```

Organizationally, you may want to put these as columns in your original dataset, as well, which you could do a variety of ways.  The simplest may be to simply `cbind` them to the dataset `x`.